# Python SignalR Client Application - How to get the ConnectionId after connection to SignalR Hub

Tags: c#, python, .net, signalr, microservices

First time poster. This is my first experience developing a microservice using .NET. Clients will use a REST API to request the service, the API will use the microservice to get results and send back to clients. The REST API is going to use SignalR to return data using a callback. There are two clients applications expected, one will be developed in .NET and another in PYTHON to consumer the service. I'm able to do a successful test using .NET client (using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client), however when I try with PYTHON client (using signalr-client), I'm not able to trigger callback from API for the specific client (if I send response to ALL clients that works). The reason I believe is that in .NET client application, after connecting to HUB, I can get ConnectionId using HubConnection.ConnectionId. Then when I make REST API call, I pass same ConnectionId and API uses the ConnectionId to send response using SignalR. However in PYTHON client, I can't find the ConnectionId attribute in Connection object. Does someone know how can I get ConnectionId in PYTHON client (or is there some other approach I need to follow).

This is the .NET client which works

```cs
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HubConnection hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:12247");
    var hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MyTestHub");
    Action<string> onUpdate = str => System.Console.WriteLine($"received: {str}");

    hubConnection.Start()
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            hubProxy.On("OnUpdateCallback", onUpdate);
        }).Wait();

    var guid = Guid.Parse(hubConnection.ConnectionId);
    var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:12247/api/Values", guid).Result;
    System.Console.ReadLine();
```

This is the PYTHON client, but how to find the ConnectionId

```py
    with Session() as session:
        connection = Connection("http://localhost:12247/signalr", session)
        hub = connection.register_hub('MyTestHub')
        connection.start()

        def onUpdate(data):
            print('received: ' + str(data))

        hub.client.on('OnUpdateCallback', onUpdate)

        with connection:
            response = requests.post("http://localhost:12247/api/Values", json=???) #how to find connectionid

    sys.stdin.readline()
```

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Have you found any solutions?